# Как парсить фотки с конкретного аккаунта Instagram в моё iOS-приложение?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, парсер, instagram

Есть инстаграм аккаунт одного певца. Нужно сделать приложение, которое будет парсить посты с его Instagram и Twitter- аккаунта.

С парсингом twitter разобрался быстро, а вот с инстаграмом - не могу.
Нашел туториал один - http://myxcode.net/2015/07/12/getting-data-from-instagram-account/

В нем все ок, только он использует фремймворк  HanekeSwift (который, к слову работает только на Swift 2). Я использую swift 3 в проекте.

Кто-то может подсказать инструменты для парсинга инстаграма?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: С логикой парсинга Instagram можно ознакомиться тут: [https://www.diggernaut.ru/blog/kak-parsit-stranitsy-saytov-s-avtopodgruzkoy-na-primere-instagram/](https://www.diggernaut.ru/blog/kak-parsit-stranitsy-saytov-s-avtopodgruzkoy-na-primere-instagram/) А потом запилить ее на нужном языке программирования.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам стоит использовать API которое предоставляет Instagram
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/